# How to reflect classes from JAR on windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, jar, classloader

Assuming the following `loader` definition *(the example is written in scala but it is almost the same as Java, thus you should easily understand the problem)*:

```
jar = new File("path/to/myjar.jar")
url = jar.toURI.toURL
urls = Array[URL](url)  // just a single-element array containing the url
loader = new URLClassLoader(urls)
```

The JAR `myjar.jar` contains `org/pack/Simple.class`. The `Simple` has standard package `org.pack` and was compiled and packed into the JAR via [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). The JAR is correct (executable etc.)

On linux, `loader.loadClass("org.pack.Simple")` returns the correct `Class` object.

On windows, it throws a `ClassNotFoundException`. Of course, I use `\` instead of `/` as a file separator.

What do I do wrong? Or does simply windows suck? I installed OracleJDK8 and added its `bin/` folder to the `path`.

**EDIT1:**

If I unpack JAR into some directory and let the ClassLoader to read from URL pointing at that directory, everything works. How is this possible?

Comment: Have you checked the file indicated by your path exists in windows? What does it URL look like? I used URLClassLoaders on Windows without issues, so it's not a case of "windows sucks".

Comment: @JPMoresmau I double checked the URL - it is in form of `file:/C:/...../myjar.jar` (i.e. forward slashes) hence I assume it is correct

Comment: @JPMoresmau I added a observation, could you please take a look at it? I'm really desperate.

Comment: Never use backslashes, it just makes your code non-portable. In addition, try a relative path and make sure `File.exists()`. The URL doesn't look right to me, shouldn't there be a double slash before the C:

Comment: @Ingo I create that file in the application and pass it as a `File` variable. Than I use URL transformation... that's the result, I don't know why the extra slash... :-(

Comment: I have similar code in some project of mine, and it does work fine on any OS. The only difference is that I create the URLCLassLoader with an additional argument that represents the *current* class loader. Unfortunately, I forgot why this was needed, and didn't write a comment, so I can't promise that it would help, but could you try it?

Comment: @Ingo what do you mena by *current loader*?

Comment: The class loader that did load the class that contained the code you are running. Can be obtained with Class#getClassLoader, i.e. `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` should do it, unless you're in a static method.

Comment: Does your jar myjar.jar contain inner classes.

Comment: @Koekiebox yes, it does

Comment: see my answer. I initially thought it was due to the Inner classes and Windows not able to handle the $ character in the filename. But then later found it was not the case.

Comment: @Koekiebox I really hate those platform-dependant behaviors :-/ However, your solution works :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled long with this problem yesterday, but after a long Googling session I stumbled on the solution.

The URL object you specify must be created as follows:

```
URLClassLoader.addURL(new File(pathParam).toURI().toURL());
```

or in the constructor as follows:

```
new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File(pathParam).toURI().toURL()},this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

***Note that the constructor has the parent class-loader as a parameter.***

for the loadClass() method. You need to ensure the path to the class is in binary format (as you are doing already).

For some reason, even if I create a URL object using the URL(String) constructor it won't work.

If you go and look at the `java.lang.ClassLoader` super-class, you will notice that it throws an exception by default. This is why the classloader is important.

```
protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
    }
```